# How can I edit/update an empty duplicate dialog box?

Tags: support, specific-question, duplicate-questions, closed-questions

I wanted to change the duplicate target for

[Why is decimal multiplication slightly inaccurate?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14368893/674039)

to

[Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

But the dialog does not have the "edit:" link that they usually have.

Comment: It was closed under the old system. The only way to fix is to re-open and re-close as a duplicate. (Then, edit out the "possible duplicate" link that was added to the top of the question as an edit, which you've already done in this case.) A gold tag badge holder should be able to do that. A mod can also do it easily.

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks. I'm kind of surprised nobody ran a script to migrate/clean up the dialogs of posts closed under the old system??

Comment: Yeah, you're not the first person to be surprised by that, and surely won't be the last...